# Twisted starting/stopping factory/protocol less noisy log messages

Tags: python, twisted

Is there a way to tell to twistd to not log all factory and protocol start and stop.
I use many type of protocols and performs a lot of connections ... and my log file grows a lot.
So i'm looking for a simple way to disable those messages.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `noisy` attribute of a factory to `False` to prevent it from logging these messages.  See also http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4021 which will probably be resolved by the next Twisted release.

For example, here's a program with two clients, but only one will log its start/stop messages:

```
import sys

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.python import log

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

f = protocol.ClientFactory()
f.protocol = protocol.Protocol
reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 22, f)

g = protocol.ClientFactory()
g.noisy = False
g.protocol = protocol.Protocol
reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 25, g)

reactor.run()
```

And the output:

```
2011-02-22 09:43:23-0500 [-] Log opened.
2011-02-22 09:43:23-0500 [-] Starting factory <twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory instance at 0x8f422cc>
^C
2011-02-22 09:43:26-0500 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2011-02-22 09:43:26-0500 [Protocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory instance at 0x8f422cc>
2011-02-22 09:43:26-0500 [-] Main loop terminated.
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your response, but i'm looking for a more system wide solution. Controlling this log messages by a log observer seems to be be really good idea so i will stand for the merging of this branch non-message-startstop-log-4021

Answer (score 0):

As a more system wide solution you can try the following:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory

Factory.noisy = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great, but you can also do this at the logging level only:

```python
import logging
logging.getLogger('twisted').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```