# How to suppress noisy factory started/stopped log messages from Twisted?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I am using twisted.web.client.Agent which in turn is using HTTP11ClientProtocol. The innumerable factory started / stopped messages are obscuring the messages that I am actually interested in. So, I am looking for a way to suppress them. Is there any?

```
2013-09-07 11:03:15+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3183638>
2013-09-07 11:03:15+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x316d050>
2013-09-07 11:03:15+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3183e18>
2013-09-07 11:03:16+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] <twisted.web._newclient.Response object at 0x3185150>
2013-09-07 11:03:16+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3183638>
2013-09-07 11:03:16+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x2dafa70>
2013-09-07 11:03:16+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3184950>
2013-09-07 11:03:16+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x317c170>
2013-09-07 11:03:16+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3186098>
2013-09-07 11:03:17+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3171248>
2013-09-07 11:03:17+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x313ef80>
2013-09-07 11:03:17+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x311dbd8>
2013-09-07 11:03:17+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x31867a0>
2013-09-07 11:03:18+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3171f80>
2013-09-07 11:03:18+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3171ea8>
2013-09-07 11:03:18+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x311de60>
2013-09-07 11:03:18+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x316d4d0>
2013-09-07 11:03:19+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x325a830>
2013-09-07 11:03:19+0530 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x325eb90>
2013-09-07 11:03:20+0530 [HTTP11ClientProtocol,client] Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x3183e18>
```

This ([Twisted starting/stopping factory/protocol less noisy log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078980/twisted-starting-stopping-factory-protocol-less-noisy-log-messages)) is a similar question, but since HTTP11ClientProtocol is not something that I am instantiating, I can't figure out where I would set the property noisy to false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want every `_HTTP11ClientFactory` in the application to hush up, you could just set the `noisy` property at the class level:

```
from twisted.web import client
client._HTTP11ClientFactory.noisy = False
```

A more flexible approach would be to create a custom `HTTPConnectionPool` that uses quiet factories and pass that to your `Agent` when you want a quieter log:

```
from twisted.web import client

class QuietHTTP11ClientFactory(client._HTTP11ClientFactory):
    noisy = False

myQuietPool = client.HTTPConnectionPool(reactor)
myQuietPool._factory = QuietHTTP11ClientFactory

agent = client.Agent(reactor, pool=myQuietPool)
```

Comment: Don't forget that `_`-prefixed attributes are private and there are no guarantees this code will continue to work in future versions of Twisted.  Please encourage people who need to rely on private APIs like this to contribute improvements upstream so that they can eventually depend on public APIs instead! :)

Comment: @snowy method1 works while method2 throws an error about some constructor not taking any parameter ...


    local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line     1086, in _newConnection
    2013-09-09 17:17:43+0530 [-]     factory = self._factory(quiescentCallback)
2013-09-09 17:17:43+0530 [-] TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Comment: @AnuvratParashar - I can't be sure of what's going on without looking at your code, but "TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments" suggests that your factory class does not properly subclass `_HTTP11ClientFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this at just the logging level:

```python
import logging
logging.getLogger('twisted').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```